# Please recommend good sources of information on water cooling or silent PC building

Tags: hardware

I've been waiting to ages to ask this question on (site-that-is-not)stackoverflow.com!

My PC is a bit of a beast. I use it for everything, including development (my day job) and gaming. It's a bit noisy though. I've tried using larger, slower fans where possible but it still hums a bit, and I'm a bit nervous of using the totally passive heat dissipation options.

Can anyone recommend any good sources for information on water cooling aimed at technically competent but ignorant noobs?

Any preference as to the fully integrated solutions (like the Zalman Reserator) versus the all-parts-in-main-case options?

Comment: Do you intend to overclock?

Comment: Not especially. I currently have a Q9450 processor and an Sapphire HD4870 Toxic gfx card. The prroc is at standard settings and the gfx card is at factory settings (which are marginally oc'd anyway). I'll probably stick with that unless my alternative cooling solution turns out to leave me with lots of headroom.

Answer (score 1):

[Hush](http://shop.hushtechnologies.com/hushshop/intellisys/index.html) make very nice silent PCs. Although they aren't user serviceable.

Tip, don't get a card reader. The holes look ugly, and it will be out of date in a few years when faster cards are available.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Sam. They look very nice indeed. Perhaps when I'm looking for a media PC for the lounge I'll consider them. Right now though, I'm looking to silence my existing (self-built) PC.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.silentpcreview.com is a site dedicated to building silent PCs.

Answer (score 1):

the forums on [bit-tech](http://forums.bit-tech.net) and [hard ocp](http://www.hardforum.com) are probably your best bet. watercooling is still very much a niche enthusiast segment. the maintenance/fiddle factor is simply too high for most corporate envrionments. I have heard that the Zalman reserator is very blingy, and not too hot performance wise (sorry no hard data to back that up, just what i hemember reading somewhere, prob a forum post...)

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend [silentpcreview](http://www.silentpcreview.com).

I build my own silent PC last year using the 
Antec P180 cabinet, and if you just search for "Antec P180" you will get tons of reviews and user stories about people that have build their own silent pc. I am satisfied with the case, although it probably is not the simplest case to use for building your own pc (I have only build that one myself so I cannot compare to others, but it was not super straight forward). But the result was very good.

Lessons learned:

- whenever you feel like physically
  modifying the case to fit what you
  are trying to do, it is a sign that
  you are doing it wrong.
- make really, really, really sure that your
  CPU fits your motherboard so you do
  not have to return it and exchange it
  with a new one... Most motherboard
  manufacturers have lists/query
  functionality on their web pages, use
  those.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, hlovdal. The machine I currently have is in a P182 case. Very nice case, actually. Quite pleased with it. Didn't go the trouble of foam coating it (like Jeff A did for Scott H). I suspect that'll help quiet the thing down but I wonder what it'll do for internal temperature?